# Returning a list of N dictionary keys that have the maximum integer values

Tags: python-3.x

`my_dict = {'label': 6, 'label_2': 5, 'label_3': 9, 'label_4': 12}`

I would like to create a list that will contain the top 2 (or 3, or 4, or 50... this will vary) dictionary keys, according to their highest values. So in the example above if I wanted the top 2, I should get:

`['label_3', 'label_4']`

for top 3 I should get:

`['label', 'label_3', 'label_4']`

And so on.

After reading some other stackoverflow threads, I've been experimenting with heapq, but can't get it to work the way I want. Would appreciate some help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort a Python dictionary by value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/sort-a-python-dictionary-by-value)

Comment: You can add your solution as an answer instead of editing in to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, the moment I post here, I find a solution (thanks to the [heapq documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest)). This works:

`my_list = heapq.nlargest(3, my_dict, key=my_dict.get)`

This will go over my_dict and return the keys with the 3 largest values.

Thanks.